# gridview динамически добавить картинку

Tags: java, android

есть такая разметка

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/grid_view"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:columnWidth="90dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
      android:numColumns="auto_fit"
      android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
      android:verticalSpacing="10dp">
```

есть такой адаптер

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext = null;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> mBitmaps = null;
private ImageView mImageViewHolder = null;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bitmap> imageViews) {
    mContext = context;
    mBitmaps = imageViews;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mBitmaps.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mBitmaps.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        mImageViewHolder = new ImageView(mContext);
        mImageViewHolder.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        mImageViewHolder.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(180, 150));
    }
    else {
        mImageViewHolder = (ImageView)convertView;
    }
    mImageViewHolder.setImageBitmap(mBitmaps.get(position));

    return mImageViewHolder;
}
```

}

как сделать чтобы можно было добавлять динамически картинку или удалить ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

добавить в `ImageAdapter`  метод вроде

```
public void addItem(Bitmap item) {
    mBitmaps.add(item);
    notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Фишка тут именно в  `notifyDatasetChanged();` Этот метод заставит адаптер применить изменения.

Comment: еще вопрос. почему если добавляем изображение больших размеров, то приложение падает ?

Comment: @ВиталийЛопатин, а посмотрите в стактрейс, и увидите почему оно падает. Но я итак знаю - на каждый пиксель разрешения картинки нужно 8 байт оперативной памяти. Посчитайте, сколько будет занимать в ней ваша большая картинка. Виртуальная машина java, которая работает в  ОС Android не может за раз выделить столько памяти, сколько нужно вашей картинке.